# get prediction intervals from Winters-Holt forecast method in python

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, predictive-models

I am trying to output predictions from a Winters-Holt forecasting model that I have made. I have found that libraries like Statsmodels have some tools to do that but impossible to find tutorials or anything to help use them. Plus, I would like to fully understand my code so I am interested in building the intervals on my own from existing Winter Holts predictions that I have:

here is what I have so far:
winter holts predictions for multiple items for which seasonality and trend has been checked before:

```
def winter_holts_high_low(x):

    deseasonalized_dat = pd.DataFrame(data1['Id'])
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-24'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-24']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-23'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-23']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-22'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-22']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-21'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-21']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-20'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-20']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-19'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-19']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-18'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-18']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-17'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-17']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-16'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-16']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-15'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-15']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-14'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-14']
    deseasonalized_dat['deseasonalize_d-13'] = data1['deseasonalize_d-13']
    deseasonalized_dat['average'] = deseasonalized_dat.mean(axis=1)

    data2['L0'] = deseasonalized_dat['average']
    # print("lo", df['L0'].loc[i])
    data2['T0'] = 0
    data2['ST0'] = data2['st13']
    # print("sto", df['ST0'].loc[i])

    data2['L1'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-12'] / (data2['st24'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L0'] + data2['T0'])
    # print("l1", df['L1'].loc[i])
    data2['T1'] = x[1] * (data2['L1'] - data2['L0']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T0']

    data2['ST1'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-12'] / data2['L1']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st24']
    # print("st1", df['ST1'].loc[i])

    data2['L2'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-11'] / (data2['st23'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L1'] + data2['T1'])
    # print("l2", df['L2'].loc[i])
    data2['T2'] = x[1] * (data2['L2'] - data2['L1']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T1']
    data2['ST2'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-11'] / data2['L2']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st23']

    data2['L3'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-10'] / (data2['st22'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L2'] + data2['T2'])
    # print("l3", df['L3'].loc[i])
    data2['T3'] = x[1] * (data2['L3'] - data2['L2']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T2']
    data2['ST3'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-10'] / data2['L3']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st22']

    data2['L4'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-9'] / (data2['st21'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L3'] + data2['T3'])
    # print("l4", df['L4'].loc[i])
    data2['T4'] = x[1] * (data2['L4'] - data2['L3']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T3']
    data2['ST4'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-9'] / data2['L4']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st21']

    data2['L5'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-8'] / (data2['st20'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L4'] + data2['T4'])
    # print("dt-8", df['Dt-8'].loc[i])
    # print("l5", df['L5'].loc[i])
    data2['T5'] = x[1] * (data2['L5'] - data2['L4']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T4']
    data2['ST5'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-8'] / data2['L5']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st20']

    data2['L6'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-7'] / (data2['st19'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L5'] + data2['T5'])
    # print("l6", df['L6'].loc[i])
    data2['T6'] = x[1] * (data2['L6'] - data2['L5']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T5']
    data2['ST6'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-7'] / data2['L6']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st19']

    data2['L7'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-6'] / (data2['st18'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L6'] + data2['T6'])
    data2['T7'] = x[1] * (data2['L7'] - data2['L6']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T6']
    data2['ST7'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-6'] / data2['L7']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st18']

    data2['L8'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-5'] / (data2['st17'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L7'] + data2['T7'])
    data2['T8'] = x[1] * (data2['L8'] - data2['L7']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T7']
    data2['ST8'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-5'] / data2['L8']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st17']

    data2['L9'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-4'] / (data2['st16'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L8'] + data2['T8'])
    data2['T9'] = x[1] * (data2['L9'] - data2['L8']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T8']
    data2['ST9'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-4'] / data2['L9']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st16']

    data2['L10'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-3'] / (data2['st15'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L9'] + data2['T9'])
    data2['T10'] = x[1] * (data2['L10'] - data2['L9']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T9']
    data2['ST10'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-3'] / data2['L10']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st15']

    data2['L11'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-2'] / (data2['st14'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L10'] + data2['T10'])
    data2['T11'] = x[1] * (data2['L11'] - data2['L10']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T10']
    data2['ST11'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-2'] / data2['L11']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st14']

    data2['L12'] = x[0] * (data2['Dt-1'] / (data2['st13'] + 0.01)) + (1 - x[0]) * (
            data2['L11'] + data2['T11'])
    data2['T12'] = x[1] * (data2['L12'] - data2['L11']) + (1 - x[1]) * data2['T11']
    data2['ST12'] = x[2] * (data2['Dt-1'] / data2['L12']) + (1 - x[2]) * data2['st13']

    # print("l12", df['L12'].loc[i])
    data2['Lt+1'] = round((data2['L12'] + data2['T12']) * data2['st24'], )
    data2['Lt+1'] = np.where((data2['Lt+1'] > 0), data2['Lt+1'], 0)
    # print("winter-holts multiplicative", df['Lt+1'].loc[i])
    data2['MSE'] = (((data2['Dt-12'] - data2['L1']) +
                     (data2['Dt-11'] - data2['L2']) +
                     (data2['Dt-10'] - data2['L3']) +
                     (data2['Dt-9'] - data2['L4']) +
                     (data2['Dt-8'] - data2['L5']) +
                     (data2['Dt-7'] - data2['L6']) +
                     (data2['Dt-6'] - data2['L7']) +
                     (data2['Dt-5'] - data2['L8']) +
                     (data2['Dt-4'] - data2['L9']) +
                     (data2['Dt-3'] - data2['L10']) +
                     (data2['Dt-2'] - data2['L11']) +
                     (data2['Dt-1'] - data2['L12'])) ** 2) / 12

    return data2['MSE'].loc[i]
```

then fonction is called and parameters are optimized:

```
for i in data2.index:
    x0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

    solver = 'SLSQP'

    if data2['seasonality_status'].loc[i] == "seasonal" and data2['trend_status'].loc[i] == "trending" and \
            data2['demand_level'].loc[i] == 'high' and data2['variability'].loc[i] == 'low':
        result = minimize(winter_holts_high_low, x0, bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method=solver,
                         tol=1, options={'maxiter': 15})
```

now from this existing code I would like to output intervals predictions but I dont know how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I struggle to find materials on it. Thank you kindly

Comment: Holt not Holts, Winters not Winter

Comment: my appologies for mixing the s in between both name, thank you for taking the time to point it out, I will update my post. Regardless, your comment is absolutely not helpful in solving the issue

Comment: I understand Glen_b